# Error if getc reads more than 4096 chars

Tags: c, multithreading, stdin

I have a problem in my program. I am reading from stdin in infinite loop it works fine but when i put more than 4096 chars into stdin it starts acting bad i dont really why. is getc limited ? I i will put you here input and output dor ilustration

```
 #define NFDS 1
 #define h_addr h_addr_list[0]
 #define BUFFER_LEN 4096
 void *sending(void *arguments)
 {
struct arg_struct *args = arguments;
            int i = 0, j = 1;
            if(signal(SIGINT, receive_signal) == SIG_ERR) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting signal handler for SIGINT.\n");
                    }
            fd_set myset;
            struct timeval tim;
            int result;
            int data_cap = 4096;
            while(running)
            {
                tim.tv_sec = 0;
                tim.tv_usec = 500;
                FD_ZERO(&myset);
                FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &myset);
                result = select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &myset, NULL, NULL, &tim);
                if(result != 0)
                {
                        str = calloc(data_cap,sizeof(char));
                        while((c = getc(stdin)) != '\n')
                        {
                            if (j >= data_cap)
                            {
                                str = realloc(str,sizeof(char) * data_cap * 2);
                                data_cap = data_cap * 2;
                            }
                            str[i] = c;
                            i++;
                            j++;
                        }
                        if (j >= data_cap)
                        {
                            str = realloc(str,sizeof(char) * data_cap * 2);
                        }
                        str[i] = '\0';
                        if(strlen(str)!=0)
                        {
                            bufferIn = message(args->arg2,str);
                                 if(send(args->arg1,bufferIn,strlen(bufferIn),0) < 0)
                            {
                                callError("ERROR: cannot send socked");
                            }
                            free(bufferIn);
                        }
                        free(str); i = 0; j = 1; data_cap = 4096;           
                }
            }
return NULL;
 }

//in main threads
  struct arg_struct args;
    args.arg1 = client_socket;
    args.arg2 = username;
 pthread_t t22;
 pthread_t t11;
 pthread_create(&t22, NULL, &sends, (void *)&args);
 pthread_create(&t11, NULL, &reci, (void *)&args);
 pthread_join(t22, NULL);
  pthread_cancel(t22);
 pthread_join(t11, NULL);
 pthread_cancel(t11);
```

input for example: aaaaaaaa.....aaaaaaaaa THIS IS THE WORD

lets imagine that there is 4096 'a' chars in a sequence from first 'a' to last 'a' 
but when i print what i got from stdin i get this:

THIS IS THE WORD
aaaaaaa......aaaaaaa THIS IS THE WORD

what it really does is at first, it reads all chars form 4096. char. In this example it is "THIS IS THE WORD" and prints it first. Than it really prints what it should print at the first place.

between all characters in no end of line symbol
at first i thougt that there is something bad with memory allocation because i alocate mamory at 4096 bytes but there is not. I tested it. 
Thak you for any help
sorry for bad english

Comment: Is there something wrong with your spacebar? The indentation is all over the place

Comment: There is a macro defined above called `BUFFER_LEN` which has a value 4096. That is used to defined a char array of size 4096. Could you be overflowing?

Comment: Could you please show only the relevant parts of the code? It's hard to read so much code when the real problem is within a much smaller code block.

Comment: No, `getc` is not limited.

Comment: edit of code is done no BUFFER LEN is not used in that problematic function

Comment: Bug: after your second `str = realloc(str,sizeof(char) * data_cap * 2);` you forget to update `data_cap`.

Comment: but i dont have to ceause finally after that i reset it to 4096

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "but i dont have to ceause finally after that i reset it to 4096" This makes zero sense. You do have to update data_cap.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment that an answer, but as it is long I posted it here as is.

Something else must be wrong because isolating the "problematic" part as:

```
  char c;
  int i=0, j=1, data_cap=4096;
  char *str = calloc(data_cap,sizeof(char));
  while((c = getc(stdin)) != '\n') {
    if (j >= data_cap) {
      str = realloc(str,sizeof(char) * data_cap * 2);
      data_cap = data_cap * 2;
    }
    str[i] = c;
    i++;
    j++;
  }
  if (j >= data_cap) {
    str = realloc(str,sizeof(char) * data_cap * 2);
  }
  str[i] = '\0';
  if(strlen(str)!=0) {
    char *bufferIn = message("test",str);
    printf("%s\n",bufferIn);
    free(bufferIn);
  }
  free(str); i = 0; j = 1; data_cap = 4096;
```

works well.

As you didn't tell us what the argument to the function are, we cannot tell more...

Comment: iam using in this program asynchron. signal hadling with paralel threads i think that thare could be some problem. becaouse you are not using select function or signal handler maybe there is a problem but did you really try input with length bigger that 4096 ?

Comment: Then you know were your problem is... What your `receive_signal` does? Are the threads doing concurrent reading the input?

Comment: no they are not one thread is checking stdin and sends message to server the second thread is waiting for server to send mesage and whrites into stdou and receive signal check if SIGINT was send to break cycle and end whole program

Comment: Yes I tested it with (very) long inputs, and it works well. Please post MVCE.

Comment: i found whats a problem here maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131105/how-to-read-over-4k-input-without-new-lines-on-a-terminal/131274#131274